# How to make a Post, Put or Delete followed by a get fetch?

Tags: rest, api, express, websocket, socket.io

I have an API written in ExpressJS. Right now I'm using a websocket server to fetch data from that API, but I'm having an issue when I do some fetch that updates (POST, PUT or DELETE) the database (Postgres) followed by a GET requisition.

I was expecting the GET fetch to give me back the list of all records, including the one I've just updated, but the new one is not being included.

Then I included a timeout between my update operation and the new GET. I know it's not a good solution because the timeout I defined may not work properly when many users are sending requests at the same time.

```
client.on('deleteData', (id) => { 

fetch(server+id, {
method: 'DELETE',
})
.then (
setTimeout(function(){ 
fetch(server)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(//params separated with ,
responseJson => { 
client.emit('getData', responseJson.data)
client.broadcast.emit('getData', responseJson.data) /
console.log(responseJson.data)
console.log("eliminated!")
}) }, 1000))
.catch((error) =>{
console.error(error)
client.emit('getData', error)
})})
```

If I take out the timeout from my code, the new update (in this case a DELETE) is not reflected in the dataset I get in the next GET.

Would someone please help me to find a way to wait for the exact time for the updated data to be available for the next GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, the GET requisition should be inside  the POST callback:

```
client.on('eliminarCliente', (id) => { 
  fetch(server+id, {
  method: 'DELETE',
  })
  .then (response => response.json())
  .then (responseJson => {
    fetch(server)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => { 
      client.emit('getData', responseJson.data)  
      client.broadcast.emit('getData', responseJson.data)
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
    client.emit('getData', error)
    })  
  })
 .catch((error) =>{
    client.emit('getData', error)
 })
})
```